# Incrementing the column value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, automation, auto-increment

I have a data as shown below.

```
table_id    store_ref     store_type
 100          store_a       1
 101          store_a       1
 102          store_a       1
```

I am trying to duplicate the records in the same table with change in table_id column value. The table id column value should auto increment.Below is the output that is expected

Output :

```
  table_id    store_ref     store_type
   100          store_a       1
   101          store_a       1
   102          store_a       1
   103          store_a       1
   104          store_a       1
   105          store_a       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, `table_id` is a `serial` column so it is set automatically.  Then you just need to do:

```
insert into t (store_ref, store_type)
    select store_ref, store_type
    from t
    order by id;
```

If `id` is not `serial` for some reason (and I can't really think of a good reason), you can calculate it:

```
insert into t (id, store_ref, store_type)
    select (max(id) over () + row_number() over (order by id)) as id,
           store_ref, store_type
    from t;
```